# C# using [Flags] with [Description]

Tags: c#, enums

I'm looking to combine the use of enumerations  - with the bitwise [Flags] - as well as using a description of the combination of the results. I've looked into examples here using the Flags Attribute, and using the Description Attribute, but not both.

Something like:

```
[Flags]
public enum ReasonCode
{
    [Description("Verified")]
    None = 0,
    [Description("Check A")]
    Reason1 = 1,
    [Description("Check B")]
    Reason2 = 2,
    [Description("Check C")]
    Reason3 = 4,
    [Description("Check D")]
    Reason4 = 8,
    [Description("Check E")]
    Reason5 = 16,
    [Description("Check F")]
    Reason6 = 32,
    [Description("Check G")]
    Reason7 = 64
}
```

I need to specify all reasons why there was a failure. Using "Reason1", etc... isn't descriptive enough for what I am looking for. I would need a much more verbose description, like "Reason1 - Check A".

For Example:


A value of 5 would be Reason1 and Reason3.

The description would then be:


Failure:

Reason1 - Check A.

Reason3 - Check C.

Is is possible to do combine descriptions like flags?

Comment: **Maybe just my opinion but:** For the sake of maintainability and extensibility you should _never harcode "Error-Messages"_ into `Attribute`s. Instead you could create a class doing the mapping from your error code to the error description and return an instance of that class from a factory (in form of an interface or abstract base class). In this way you can always change the messages (and their source (maybe you want to load them from a file or a database in the future)) while the changes are contained to that single class (or other classes that inherit from it).

Comment: @CodeNotFound It did solve my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to produce the result you are looking for, use the following code:

```
public static String GetDescription(ReasonCode reasonCode)
{
    if (reasonCode == ReasonCode.None)
        return "Verified";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Failed:");

    foreach (ReasonCode rc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReasonCode)).Cast<ReasonCode>())
    {
        if (rc == ReasonCode.None)
            continue;

        if (reasonCode.HasFlag(rc))
            sb.AppendLine(rc.ToString() + " - " + GetEnumDescription(rc));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The code used to retrieve the description value is based on [this](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_use_and_retrieve_enum_description_attribute) implementation:

```
public static String GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    String valueText = value.ToString();
    Type type = value.GetType();

    FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(valueText);
    Object[] attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute attribute = (DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0];
        return attribute.Description;
    }

    return valueText;
}
```

You can find a working demo [*here*](http://rextester.com/GKT38144).

Comment: Thank you for the help! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more generic extension method that I have used which will deal with all enum values including flag combinations:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    //pull out each value in case of flag enumeration
    var values = value.ToString().Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
    var type = value.GetType();

    return string.Join(" | ", values.Select(enumValue => type.GetMember(enumValue)
       .FirstOrDefault()
       ?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
       ?.Description
       ?? enumValue.ToString()));
}
```

If a description attribute is not present then it will simply return the value itself.